# Haskell breaking up words by first space

Tags: string, haskell

*Note this is not the same as using the words function.*

I would like to convert from this:

```
"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."
```

into this:

```
["The"," quick"," brown"," fox"," jumped"," over"," the"," lazy"," dogs."]
```

Note how the breaks are on the first space after each word.

The best I could come up with is this:

```
parts "" = []
parts s  = if null a then (c ++ e):parts f else a:parts b
    where
    (a, b) = break isSpace s
    (c, d) = span isSpace s
    (e, f) = break isSpace d
```

It just looks a little inelegant. Can anyone think of a better way to express this?

Comment: What you want is obviously *similar* to the `words` function, so maybe you should look at how `words` is implemented and see if you can do something similar.

Comment: ... and you can see that implementation here: http://darcs.haskell.org/packages/base/Data/List.hs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**edit** -- Sorry I didn't read the question. Hopefully this new answer does what you want.

```
> List.groupBy (\x y -> y /= ' ') "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."
["The"," quick"," brown"," fox"," jumped"," over"," the"," lazy"," dogs."]
```

The library function `groupBy` takes a predicate function that tells you whether you add the next element, *y* to the previous list, which starts with *x*, or start a new list.

In this case, we don't care what the current list started with, we only want to start a new list (i.e. make the predicate evaluate to false) when the next element, *y*, is a space.

#### edit

n.m. points out that the handling of multiple spaces is not correct. In which case you can switch to `Data.List.HT`, which has the semantics you'd want.

```
> import Data.List.HT as HT
> HT.groupBy (\x y -> y /= ' ' || x == ' ') "a  b c d"
["a","  b"," c"," d"]
```

the different semantics that makes this work is that the *x* is the last element in the previous list (that you might add *y* to, or create a new list).

Comment: Looks a bit like this problem, from not so long ago! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966151/haskell-list-created-evaluating-list-elements

Comment: `chains (\x y -> isSpace x || (not . isSpace) y)` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing lots of slightly different types of splits, have a look at the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.4.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) package.  The package lets you define this split as `split (onSublist [" "])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
words2 xs = head w : (map (' ':) $ tail w)
  where w = words xs
```

And here's with arrows and applicative: (not recommended for practical use)

```
words3 = words >>> (:) <$> head <*> (map (' ':) . tail)
```

EDIT: My first solution is wrong, because it eats additional spaces. Here's the correct one:

```
words4 = foldr (\x acc -> if x == ' ' || head acc == "" || (head $ head acc) /= ' '  
                             then (x : head acc) : tail acc
                             else [x] : acc) [""]
```

Comment: This does not keep original spaces

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take

```
break2 :: (a->a->Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
break2 f (x:(xs@(y:ys))) = if f x y then ([x],xs) else (x:u,us) 
                              where (u,us) = break2 f xs
break2 f xs = (xs, [])

onSpace x y = not (isSpace x) && isSpace y

words2 "" = []
words2 xs = y : words2 ys where (y,ys) = break2 onSpace xs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parts xs = foldr spl [] xs where
   spl x [] = [[x]]
   spl ' ' (xs:xss) = (' ':xs):xss    
   spl x xss@((' ':_):_) = [x]:xss    
   spl x (xs:xss) = (x:xs):xss
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of the split package but `split (onSublist [" "])` doesn't do what I want and I can't find a solution that splits on one-or-more spaces.

Also like the solution using `Data.List.HT` but I'd like to stay away from dependencies if possible.

Cleanest I can come up with:

```
parts s 
    | null s    = []
    | null a    = (c ++ e) : parts f
    | otherwise = a        : parts b
    where
    (a, b) = break isSpace s
    (c, d) = span  isSpace s
    (e, f) = break isSpace d
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here it is. Enjoy! :D**

```
 words' :: String -> [String]
    words' [] = []
    words' te@(x:xs) | x==' ' || x=='\t' || x=='\n' = words' xs
                     | otherwise                = a : words' b
      where
        (a, b) = break isSpace te
```